# Chrome Extension - Pass URL argument (google-chrome http://www.google.com)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've developed a chrome extension/kiosk app that opens up Google Chrome in a "kiosk mode" with 4 navigation buttons, HOME, RELOAD, BACK and FORWARD. So it's basically an application that opens up Chrome in a window without Omnibox but added 4 buttons.
This is because the user should not be able to change URL or anything else. Just navigate via the web interface and the 4 simple buttons.

Now, this application/extension is packed with a hardcoded URL. Which means you can't change the URL.

in my browser.html I have the following code:

```
<webview src="http://www.example.com/" style="width:100%; height:100%"></webview>
```

and in my browser.js I have the following code:

```
document.querySelector('#home').onclick = function() {
navigateTo('http://www.example.com/');
};
```

As you can see the URL is hardcoded both in HTML file and the javascript file.

My question is. Can I change the URL so it's not hardcoded in the extension/kiosk app?
So if I type `google-chrome --app-id="jlfmnfhdcdmkibjnbeajhedeoahajnfc" http://www.google.com`
into a terminal or cmd, I would want google.com to be displayed.

There may be a simple solution or no solution at all. This is my first attempt at making a chrome extension/kiosk app. So I'm an amateur in this area.

If you want to take a look at the source code, then you can find it on [github](https://github.com/HeadlessChild/chrome-kiosk).

Comment: This is an interesting question. I very much doubt the app can access command line arguments or environment variables; but there may be another good way to pass such information. What other options would you consider?